# CMake & Visual Studio project setup

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I'm writing my own minecraft launcher in c++ with Visual Studio 2019 IDE. I want it to be a cross-platform project. I decided to use CMake for this, but I have some problems with third party libraries.

**FILE STRUCTURE**

```
root
|---MyProject
|   |---build
|   |   |---Debug
|   |   |---Release
|   |---include
|   |   |---MyProject.hpp
|   |---src
|   |   |---MyProject.cpp
|   |   |---CMakeLists.txt
|   |---CMakeLists.txt
|---Vendor
|   |---CURL
|   |   |--- // source downloaded from https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.64.1.tar.gz
|   |---CMakeLists.txt
|---CMakeLists.txt
```

I have some experience with linking libraries in visual studio's solutions, but I don't know how to do it in CMake.

I have two folders:

1. My project (which I'm working on) folder with all the .cpp and .hpp files.
2. Vendor folder for all the third party libs.

I want to link CMake projects in 'Vendor' to 'MyProject' to be able to use it in 'MyProject.cpp' and build it.

Example usage:

'MyProject.hpp':

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#inlcude "curl/curl.h"
```

'MyProject.cpp':

```
int main() {
    // Hello World
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    // Some Curl stuff
    CURL* curl;
    ...
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
add_subdirectory("Vendor/CURL")
include_directories("Vendor/CURL/include")
```

I'm new to CMake and don't know how to do it...
I was googling it for more than one hour, but I didn't find anything.
BTW: Sorry for my english.

Comment: Have you linked the Vendor projects to MyProject using target_link_libraries()?

Comment: And, although it is not part of your question, I want to point out that include_directories() should not be used. If CURL is properly set up in CMake (which I do not know, I have never used it), then target_link_libraries() should take care of the include directories. Imo, this is a great talk about CMake in general and also why you should not use include_directories(): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsXLMQ6WgIk

Comment: @Lehks Ok, thanks I will look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link to a 3rd party library you will need to specify the path and name of the library.

> I have some experience with linking libraries in visual studio's
>   solutions, but I don't know how to do it in CMake.

CMake `link_directories` maps to VS `Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories`

CMake `target_link_libraries` maps to VS `Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`

> I'm new to CMake and don't know how to do it.

Take a look at [CMake and Visual Studio](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/cmake-and-visual-studio) which explains CMake in the context of Visual Studio with an example.